# Generate HTML report for JGiven with SBT

Tags: playframework, sbt, bdd, playframework-2.3, jgiven

I am using JGiven for my tests in one of my Play 2.3.x application. The [documentation](http://jgiven.org/docs/reportgeneration/) explains how to generate HTML reports for Maven and Gradle. But nothing is available for SBT.

Is there any workaround to generate reports at the end of the tests ? Maybe by adding something in `build.sbt` ? I tried to play with "javaOptions in Tests" but couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: The documentation describes in section "HTML Report" a plain Java way to do this by calling `com.tngtech.jgiven.report.ReportGenerator` and passing arguments via the command line. The Gradle integration is actually just calling this main method's class and passing the command line parameters as as arguments. Is this enough documentation to integrate it into sbt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below my solution using a dedicated SBT task.

1. First add the `jgiven-html5-report` dependency:

`libraryDependencies += "com.tngtech.jgiven" % "jgiven-html5-report" % "0.15.3" % "test"`

2. Then declare a new task. Let's call it `livingDocumentation`:

`lazy val livingDocumentation = taskKey[Unit]("Generate HTML5 JGiven report")`
`livingDocumentation := Def.sequential(
  test in Test,
  runMain in Test toTask " com.tngtech.jgiven.report.ReportGenerator"
 ).value`

Using `Def.sequential`, I can chain 2 tasks and ensure the source JSON reports are available.

3. Finally, run the SBT task using `sbt livingDocumentation`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know SBT in detail, however, as @ahus1 already mentions in his comment, you can just call the `com.tngtech.jgiven.report.ReportGenerator` main class. For example:

build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.tngtech.jgiven" % "jgiven-html5-report" % "0.9.3"
```

On the command line:

```
$ sbt
> run-main com.tngtech.jgiven.report.ReportGenerator --sourceDir=target/jgiven-reports/json/ --targetDir=target/jgiven-reports/html
```

It would be great if you could tell me if your final solution, so that I can document it in the JGiven documentation.